# Where did Gerrit de Veer publish his diary?

Tags: textual-history, dutch-language, gerrit-de-veer, diary

Not so long ago I saw the film [Nova Zembla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_Zembla_(film)), a fictionalized retelling of the voyage as described in [Gerrit de Veer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_de_Veer)'s diary.

On his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_de_Veer), there is only one mention about his published diary:

> Map of the discovered West coast of Novaya Zemlya, from **de Veer's published diary (1598)**.

Are there any known facts about how or where (place or publisher) he published his diary so that it became famous which led to the adaptation of the film?

Comment: The answer may well be in [this article](http://www.genios.de/presse-archiv/artikel/FAS/20111002/ein-heisses-bad-in-der-eiswueste/SD1201110023247595.html). The [German Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_de_Veer#cite_note-1) on de Veer says, cited to that article, that "De Veer published the diary very soon after his return. It experienced editions in different languages ​​and was also illustrated and colored." Someone who's paid for access to Genios articles should be able to read it and find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some history of the early publication of his diary in various languages to be found in the [Introduction to the First Edition](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=y4HpAAAAMAAJ&q=%22with%20respect%20to%20the%20personal%20history%22&q=%22with%20respect%20to%20the%20personal%20history%22&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22with%20respect%20to%20the%20personal%20history%22&f=false) pages clvi-clxviii of the English translation, *The Three Voyages of William Barents to the Arctic Regions, (1594, 1595, and 1596)*

The very first publication relating to the voyages was in Amsterdam in 1598, in Dutch. The were further editions in 1599 and 1605. Latin, French, Italian and German translations followed within a year or two of the first edition. The original English translation seems to date from 1609.